# How do I preserve radio button and check box value without using cookies after the browser refresh?

Tags: javascript

I have three radio buttons and 4 check boxes.

I want to preserve the radio button and check box values after the browser refresh.

I do not want to use cookies (due to some other reason).

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible because HTTP is stateless, cookies or server side scripting provide 'state'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sessions instead.

EDIT:  My bad, I read PHP and not Javascript.  However I did find this link after a quick Google search. [Session variables without cookies in JS](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the hash url.

something like this (don't remember if you need to specify the name of the page as well, but I don't think so):

```
document.location.href = '#radio1=1&radio2=0'
```

The hash means it just directs things on the current page and not going to another page (and the browser updates it in the address field, so if the user reloads the page, it will still be there). Then you can read it from javascript as well and set it.

Not as good as using server side sessions, but it is an option :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a form to trigger a new page loading you can make the onsubmit event call a javascript function to change the window location and append URL parameters that store the values of the radio buttons. When the page loads you would then read the parameter values from the URL. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeURL(){
        var str = window.location+"?radio1=1";
        window.open(str);
        return false;

    }
    </script>
```

...

```
<FORM onsubmit="changeURL();">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" value="click me" >
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

A new facility is being developed to allow web sites to store persistent data on the client machine. Available in some browsers already this allows you to save the the radio and checkbox states and recover and restore them next time the user visits your site. For more info see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage and here http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage

Answer (score 0):

Have some JS on the page submit all radiobutton/checkbox events to the server, and store their state in your database.  When the page (re)loads, send this state as part of the HTML.